# Programmatically start Animatable (AnimatedVectorDrawable) at a particular offset

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable, objectanimator

Is there a way to programmatically start an `AnimatedVectorDrawable` at a particular offset?

**Context:**

I'm developing for API 19 and up, so I'm using Android Jetpack. I have a custom `View` with an animatable "indicator" (a `<selector>` with vector images).

The way I currently start my animation is as follows:

```java
ImageView indicator = findViewById(R.id.indicator);
indicatorDrawable = indicator.getDrawable().getCurrent();
if(indicatorDrawable instanceof Animatable) {
    ((Animatable) indicatorDrawable).start();
}
```

And this is the animator, associated with my "indicator", in xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
        android:valueFrom="0.5"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

This all works fine. However, I have multiple instances of my custom `View` in an `Activity` and I need to synchronize their "indicator" animations (which can individually switch on or off at any time).

I won't bother you with the details, but I currently have an acceptable solution that basically uses a `static` millisecond field in my custom `View`. It works, but it causes the animations to stall for some time, if they are trying to catch up.

I'd much rather immediately start the animation at a particular offset, to avoid this stalling.

I would think I should somehow be able to access above `ObjectAnimator` associated with my `Animatable`, and set its `startOffset`, but I can't figure out how.

---

So, can I somehow access the `ObjectAnimator` and individually set its `startOffset` for each individual `Animatable`, programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional searching on the interwebs I found the library [Kyrie](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/kyrie), by
[Alex Lockwood](https://github.com/alexjlockwood), which suggests the following about the standard implementation of `VectorDrawable` and `AnimatedVectorDrawable`:

> However, these two classes have three main limitations:
>
> 1. They can't be paused, resumed, or seeked.

... and addresses those issues.

Then, after some more searching, I came across a new Android Jetpack package, [androidx.vectordrawable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/vectordrawable), that addresses these issues as well, in particular: *androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-seekable:1.0.0*.

Therefore, it appears it simply is not possible to seek to a particular offset with the default implementation of `AnimatedVectorDrawable`.

So, now I just have to figure out how this new Android Jetpack package works and see if it's worth the additional overhead.